# Parsing raw string with embedded quotes into a list with lua

Tags: lua

Parsing a string by specifying a delimiter is easy enough.  There are many examples.  However, I'm having trouble splitting a raw string with embedded double or single quotes:

```
item1;item2 "x;y;z";item3 args='arg1;arg2;arg3';item4
```

I want the following result when splitting with `;` as a delimiter:

```
item1
item2 "x;y;z"
item3 args='arg1;arg2;arg3'
item4
```

Comment: Thanks.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it the 'old-fashion' way, i.e., without built-in pattern matching:

```
function parse(s,target)
  local line = ''
  local quote
  for c = 1,#s do
    c = s:sub(c,c)
    if c == quote then
      quote = nil
    elseif quote == nil and (c == '"' or c == "'") then
      quote = c
    end
    if quote or c ~= target then
      line = line .. c
    else
      print(line)
      line = ''
    end
  end
  print(line)
end

local s = [[item1;item2 "x;y;z";item3 args='arg1;arg2;arg3';item4]]
parse(s,';')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
local str = [[item1;item2 "x;y;z";item3 args='arg1;arg2;arg3';;item5]]

for part in ('""'..str..';')
   :gsub(
      "((['\"]).-%2)([^'\"]*)",
      function(q, _, u) return q..u:gsub(";", "\0") end)
   :sub(3)
   :gmatch"(%Z*)%z"
do
   print(part)
end
```

Comment: Works great.  Thanks.